# How to Use Circe for Decoding JSON Lists with Different Data Types in Scala

Tags: scala, circe

There is a complex json object. The "value" field in decode can have different types.
I am new to scala so I will be grateful for any idea to do so.

```
{"price":0, 

"price_currency":"USD", 

"decode":[ 

   {"label":"Make","value":"BMW"}, 

   {"label":"Model Year","value":2017}, 

   {"label": "Equipment", "value": [ "Liftgate", "Packages"] }

   {"label": "Price", "value": [

        {"date": "2015-06-10", "price": 20500,"currency": "EUR"},
        { "date": "2015-09-21", "price": 20000,"currency": "EUR"}
    ]}

]}
```

the "value" field has different types: Double, String, Seq [String], object
I tried to create a common trait for these types and a custom decoder, but it turned out

**UPDATE**
hi, I want to share a solution
for such a structure, it was possible to make implicit

```
case class VinInfo (price: Double,
                    price_currency: String,
                    decode: Seq[VinDecodeDetails])

sealed trait VinDecodeDetails

case class VinDecodeString(label: String, value: String) extends VinDecodeDetails

case class VinDecodeEquipment(label: String, value: Seq[String]) extends VinDecodeDetails

case class VinDecodePrice(label: String, value: Seq[VinPrice]) extends VinDecodeDetails

case class VinPrice(date: String, price: Double, currency: String)

object VinDecodeDetails
```

```
  implicit val eitherDoubleOrString: Decoder[Either[Double, String]] =
    Decoder[Double].map(Left(_)).or(Decoder[String].map(Right(_)))

  implicit val decodeVinInfo: Decoder[VinInfo] = new Decoder[VinInfo] {
    final def apply(c: HCursor): Decoder.Result[VinInfo] =
      for {
        price <- c.downField("price").as[Double]
        price_currency <- c.downField("price_currency").as[String]
        decode <- c.downField("decode").as[Seq[VinDecodeDetails]]
      } yield {
        new VinInfo(price, price_currency, decode)
      }
  }

  implicit val decodeVinDecodeDetails: Decoder[VinDecodeDetails] = new Decoder[VinDecodeDetails] {
    final def apply(c: HCursor): Decoder.Result[VinDecodeDetails] =
      for {
        decodeLabel <- c.downField("label").as[String]
        value = c.downField("value")
        vinDecodeDetails <- decodeLabel match {
          case "Equipment" => value.as[Seq[String]]
          case "Price"     => value.as[Seq[VinPrice]]
          case _ => value.as[Either[Double, String]].map{
            case Right(s) => s.toString
            case Left(d) => d.toString
          }
        }
      } yield {
        decodeLabel match {
          case "Equipment" => VinDecodeEquipment("Equipment", vinDecodeDetails.asInstanceOf[Seq[String]])
          case "Price"     => VinDecodePrice("Price", vinDecodeDetails.asInstanceOf[Seq[VinPrice]])
          case _ => VinDecodeString(decodeLabel, vinDecodeDetails.asInstanceOf[String])
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: you just need to define your custom reader for your value type.

Comment: You can use any json-formatter to format your json properly.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I don't think "you just need to define your custom reader for your value type" is a helpful answer.

Comment: This really depends a lot on what you want your Scala model to look like. It might be better to start on that side, and then work out the mapping.

Comment: @TravisBrown without any information given about the tried code... this is the best I can come up with (other than just giving the implementation). And "This really depends a lot on what you want your Scala model to look like. It might be better to start on that side, and then work out the mapping." does not seem any more helpful.